# What is the default connection pool sizes in c3p0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In the below config, If I missed initial, max, min pool size. What will be the default connection pool sizes in c3p0?

```xml
<bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${dbDriver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dbURL}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${dbUsername}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dbPassword}"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The InitialPoolSize is 3 by default.

You can check the below links for more info:

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#initialPoolSize

http://javatech.org/2007/11/c3p0-connectionpool-configuration-rules-of-thumb/

Comment: +1 for quoting documentation, this should have been accepted answer.

Comment: NB that you can set these values also in c3p0.properties or hibernate's config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520978/32453

Answer (score 6):

Excerpt from [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0Defaults`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.2-pre8/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/C3P0Defaults.java):

```
private final static int INITIAL_POOL_SIZE     = 3;  
private final static int MIN_POOL_SIZE         = 3;
private final static int MAX_POOL_SIZE         = 15;
```

However if it's not documented, don't rely on default.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link further helpful. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool